# How to use Eclipse IDE in git on a Windows/Linux repository

Tags: git, eclipse

I have an Eclipse project in a folder with other projects. One of the projects is on Windows and the other project is Eclipse on Linux, all in the same git repository. I share the repository on Linux & Windows.

Every time I clone a new copy of the Eclipse repository on Linux, I have to re-add the project and re-add all settings. Is there a way to avoid this, ie. include the settings in the git check-in?

Note: Re-Adding the project isn't really a big deal but re-configuring all of the code formatting every time is a big pain (`Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Code Style` -> `Formatter`). This configuration is more complicated and takes a long time every time.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to avoid checking in the Eclipse dot files.  It's best to let Eclipse generate those.

It doesn't make sense that you'd have to reenter the formatter settings each time.  Clearly, that is not part of the project, but the Eclipse preferences.